# Weak compositions with bounded partial sums

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Is there an easy way to count the number of weak m-compositions of n whose partial sums are lower bounded by some function?

Example:

Let K be a weak 3-composition of 4

K = (k1, k2, k3)

Let s(t) be the partial sum of the first t members of K. s(3) = 4

How many unique Ks are there if s(t) >= t

Comment: What does "weak" mean here?

Comment: weak means the members are non-negative. A regular composition has all positive members. A weak composition can have zeros.